# In Timelike Infinity, why do the Friends of Wigner wait to start the Project?

Tags: xeelee-sequence

In [Timelike Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timelike_Infinity), the Friends of Wigner escape the Qax Occupation 1,500 years into the past. Their goal is to enact the Project, using the singularities they possess to turn Jupiter into a black hole.

However, after arriving in the past, they don't actually enact the Project; instead, they seem content to do nothing for a year until the arrival of Michael Poole and the Qax pursuers. Why?

---

Ideas I've had and discarded:

1. *They're not in the right place.* They are already in orbit around Jupiter, so there is no large distance to travel. They have a fully functioning hyperdrive, so are maneuverable. It is mentioned that they easily evade the human ships of the past with it.
2. *They need resources they don't have.* They already have the singularities. They are self-sufficient for at least a year. They have turned down all communication with the humans in the past. If they need any resources there's no indication of them doing anything to get them.
3. *They need time to enact the Project.* The fact that they have a year in the past before the Qax pursue is only due to the Qax Governor's reticence at following, something they would have known nothing about; one would assume their original plan would be based off of being immediately pursued. If they knew they wouldn't be able to immediately do it, you'd assume they'd instead do some other task: hide, travel away, etc.
4. *They decided not to initiate the Project until they were under threat.* When the Qax do show up, the Friends are unable to initiate the Project until well after they are under attack, at which point it is too late. It doesn't make sense that a group that believes that the Project justifies any and all means and makes everything else irrelevant would wait at all unless necessary.

---

I *know* that the answer is "so that the characters can all be together to see what's going on", but I'm hoping that there's some in-story reason that I overlooked. It seems an odd narrative choice to place Michael Poole a year away from Jupiter, but then not justify, reference, or use the delay somehow in the story.